# Mockito: mock a subscriptable class

Tags: python, mockito

I would like to mock ConfigParser class with Mockito to perform a simple test:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

from unittest import TestCase
from mockito import when, mock, verify

section = "SETTINGS"

# Here is an example function to test

def get_config():
    ini_file = "settings.ini"

    parser = ConfigParser()

    parser.read(ini_file)
    settings = parser[section]

    db_name = settings['db_name']
    db_type = settings['db_type']

    return (db_name, db_type)

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def test_0_check_get_config(self):
        parser = mock(ConfigParser)

        expected_db_name = 'test.sqlite'
        expected_db_type = 'sqlite'

        settings = {
            'db_name': expected_db_name,
            'db_type': expected_db_type
        }

        # The line above will fail: TypeError: 'Dummy' object is not subscriptable
        # I need to make the mocked class to return a 'settings' dictionary when 'SETTINGS' key is requested.
        when(parser[section]).thenReturn(settings)

        db_name, db_type = get_config()

        assert db_name == 'test.sqlite'
        assert db_type == 'sqlite'
```

The code is very self-explanatory. I would like the mocked class to return a corresponding dictionary when a particular key is requested.

There are a plenty of similar questions regarding 'regular' python unittest module. However, I would like to find an answer for Mockito mocking.

Comment: should it not be settings = mock({'db_name':....})  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stub ("when") the special *dunder* functions.  E.g.

```
In [1]: from mockito import *

In [2]: m = mock()

In [3]: when(m).__getitem__("hi").thenReturn("ho")
Out[3]: <mockito.invocation.AnswerSelector at 0x1da3ba1d300>

In [4]: m["hi"]
Out[4]: 'ho'
```

This solves the "subscriptable" problem but keep in mind that the exact example you gave uses a global `ConfigParser` (t.i. you don't dependency inject here).  Just calling `mock(ConfigParser)` will not monkey-patch the global object.  Instead it creates a *new* object ("instance") you can pass around ("inject").